# End if not recognizing the original if statement and keeps giving a compile error

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am brand new to coding, and I keep getting a compile error "End If without block if" when I go to run my code. Below is what I have.

```
Sub CompareAndFormatWithGradient()
Dim rateChart1 As Range
Dim rateChart2 As Range
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

' Set the worksheet where the data is located
Set ws = Worksheets("Rolling Data Ranked")

' Set the ranges for the two charts
Set rateChart1 = ws.Range("E56:Q56")
Set rateChart2 = ws.Range("W56:AI56")

' Loop through each cell to format
    For Each cell1 In rateChart1
        For Each cell2 In rateChart2
            If cell1.Value > cell2.Value Then
                With cell1.Interior  'Start Gold
                    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
                    .Gradient.Degree = 45
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
                End With
                With cell1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                    .Color = 49407
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                With cell1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                    .Color = 65535
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With ' End Gold
                With cell2.Interior ' Start Silver
                    .Pattern = x1PatternLinearGradient
                    .Gradient.Degree = 45
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
                End With
                With cell2.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                    .Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                With cell2.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                    .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With ' End Silver
            ElseIf cell1.Value < cell2.Value Then
                With cell1.Interior ' Start Silver
                    .Pattern = x1PatternLinearGradient
                    .Gradient.Degree = 45
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
                End With
                With cell1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                    .Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                With cell1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                    .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                With cell1.Interior  'Start Gold
                    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
                    .Gradient.Degree = 45
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
                End With
                With cell1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                    .Color = 49407
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                With cell1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                    .Color = 65535
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell1
End Sub
```

I tried adding and taking away the end if statements, but it either pops the same error or says next without for

Comment: `With cell1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)` is missing an `End With`

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems, the one that is causing the compile error is that `With cell1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)` is missing an `End With`.

Secondly, I guess you are not using `Option Explicit` (at the top of the Module ... you should always use this otherwise VBA is just hiding problems from you) and so you are not detecting that in two places you are using `x1PatternLinearGradient` (the second character is a digit '1') instead of `xlPatternLinearGradient` (the second character is a letter 'l')

Comment: Ah good catch, didn't even see that when zoning on a missing "End ..."

Answer (score 1):

There's no End With at

```
        With cell1.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
            .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        With cell1.Interior  'Start Gold
```